# ColdFusion character encoding issue

Tags: coldfusion, character-encoding

Let me start out by saying my end goal (in case I'm incorrect in any of my assumptions or understanding of character encoding): I want the characters of my webpages to display correctly, even if I paste in unique characters from Word or other programs.

Hopefully this can work most times without having to pass it through some encoding function on the server-side. I'm always working with US English and pasting from Word, so it doesn't seem like it should be that difficult.

It seems to me that ColdFusion is messing up my character encoding and displaying apostrophe's (probably pasted from Word) as â€™. My page works as a .htm file, but as soon as I rename extension to .cfm, it doesn't. See here:

- http://www.viktorwithak.com/Temp/utf8.htm
- http://www.viktorwithak.com/Temp/utf8.cfm

Here's what I'm seeing, in case you get anything different:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bxf6o.png
(Looks like the one that works says Content-Type is text/html, and the one that doesn't has Content-Type: text/html; charset-UTF-8)

Suggestions? (Am I correct that UTF-8 should be the correct encoding?)

Edit: for convenience, my source for both files:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>utf-8</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Make sure you don’t pack your toiletries or clothes for your travel day.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you show the cfm code ?

Comment: The CFM code is _exactly_ the same as the HTML source code in the example above it, even though the rendered output is different. (After creating the HTM file I just did Save As and then replaced the extension.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What editor are you using?  If you're using CFBuilder2+ the [BOM mark](http://java.dzone.com/articles/what-does-utf-8-bom-mean) should made everything UTF-8 by default.  However if you're not, and your editor has no settings on setting BOM mark, then you'll need to use this as the first line of your cfm.

```
<cfprocessingdirective pageEncoding="utf-8">
```

Comment: I'm using Sublime Text 2, and I've done File->Save With Encoding->UTF-8, but no luck.

EDIT: I should clarify that the .cfm file itself does indeed appear to be UTF-8 encoded, but that has no effect on the output.

Comment: I've just added the processing directive, and that works. Thank you. Do you know if there's a global setting to set that across the entire application? (I would hate to have to include that line on every single page on my server.)

Comment: `UTF-8 with BOM` in Sublime Text 2? http://blog.toshredsyousay.com/post/27543408832/how-to-add-or-remove-a-byte-order-mark

Comment: Interesting. I removed the processing directive, saved as UTF-8 with BOM, and it works. It appears I can change the default in sublime-settings as well. BOM is new to me though - any potential pitfalls of saving all web dev files as UTF-8 with BOM? (Will it work fine with all web dev file types?)

Comment: AFAIK no pitfalls, just use it. :)

Comment: Thanks for your help! All set. Seems odd to me that ColdFusion requires BOM to display UTF-8 correctly when others can interpret UTF-8 files correctly without. But whatever. It works. :)

Comment: related thread: http://forums.adobe.com/thread/930550 seems like `-Dfile.encoding=UTF8` would work but I haven't tried.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was hoping for! Unfortunately my production server is on shared ColdFusion hosting without access to the Admin, but that's an entirely separate issue I need to address with my boss. :)

Comment: To make that tag apply to all pages in an application, I would would put it in the onRequestStart() method of my Application.cfc

Comment: @DanBracuk are you sure that works?  I tried it yrs ago and it didn't because cfprossingdirective doesn't carry over whatever file being included.