# Why coldfusion is replacing 'é' by '?' when I read from URL

Tags: apache, coldfusion, escaping, html-escape-characters

In my server I have an instruction like `writeDump(URL.vehicle)`, and in my URL I have something like `myweb.co.uk?vehicle=Coupé`, but in my code I get Coup?, 
does somebody know why is happening it and how can I solve it?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ColdFusion character encoding issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22485224/coldfusion-character-encoding-issue)

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan that's not the same situation: the issue you've linked to is related to *code*, this is related to runtime values (despite the mention of "code" in the question).

Comment: @vicentJHGA, when you say "but in my code", do you mean "In the display". Because you don't mention any *code* which has `Coupé` in it... just the URL. I presume this is because you are not setting the character encoding for the response to be correct: you're telling it's ISO-8859-1 or something, whereas yer sending UTF-8. Add the appropriate headers to the response. You might also need to use `setEncoding()` (https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-s/setencoding.html) to tell CF the encoding used on the URL.

Comment: In my code I mean if I writeDump(URL) the screen appear coup? but the really weird thing is that I have another server with the same code and it does work fine. Could be some kind of configuration on the server?

Answer (score 2):

**In older versions of ColdFusion**

Try using `URLEndodedFormat()`

```
 <a href="myweb.co.uk?vehicle=#URLEncodedFormat(url.vehicle)#">...
```

https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-t-z/urlencodedformat.html

**In ColdFusion 11 or higher**

Try using `EncodeForURL()`

```
 <a href="myweb.co.uk?vehicle=#EncodeForURL(url.vehicle)#">...
```

https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-e-g/encodeforurl.html

Either one of these will escape out any special characters